# How to add Bing UET tag using Tealium

Tags: tealium, bing-ads-api

I'm new to Tealium tag management, and wanted to know how to add Bing UET tag using a Tealium custom container. I've already added Bing UET tag using Bing Ad template. But for conversion tracking I need to push a event on confirmation page.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to our sample website for using UET with Tealium: http://bingadsuet.azurewebsites.net/TealiumBasic.html. The document mentioned in step #2 covers custom events. I hope this helps!